# lua - my code displays no errors but doesn't work

Tags: lua, roblox

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local CoinsCollected = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    CoinsCollected.Name = "Coins"
end)

local AppleCoinRedClone = game.Workspace.AppleCoinRedClone
local Debounce = false
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

wait(1)

AppleCoinRedClone.Touched:Connect(function(PartB)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(PartB.Parent)
    if not player then return end
    local leaderstats = player.leaderstats
    local CoinsCollected = leaderstats.Coins
    if PartB.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        if not Debounce then
            Debounce = true
            CoinsCollected.Value = CoinsCollected.Value + 30
            wait(3)
            Debounce = false
        end
    end
end)
```

It works on the first coin that is inside the game by default but not on the coins after. There is only 1 coin in workspace at once.

i'm trying to, in the bottom half of the code to make it so that when the coin that spawns in 10 seconds after the previous has been collected, to add to the "coins" score by +30. I have tried re - ordering the code but it only gives me errors. the code only works on the first coin that is already in the workspace by default. Please, does anyone know the problem and can help me out?

Comment: I don't see code related to spawning another coin

Comment: the code spawning another coin is in a different script. it all works but this script does not work.

Comment: My guess is you spawned the coin without touch callback

Comment: what is a touch callback. The code that spawns the coin works but the code which gives you money when you collect the coin works for the 1st but not the rest of the coins that get spawned after time

Comment: Do you understand what the second part of your posted code does? Did you made sure that this code is called (the touch callback) for every additional spawned coin?

Comment: i don't know how to callback for every additional coin spawned in. nothing on google explains how to do it.

Comment: You did it in your code. I don't know how you cloned your additional coins but it should not differ much from your first coin.

Comment: first coin is in by default and the rest are cloned into the workspace. Do you know how to fix the problem though?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of the `end)` block at line six. It blocks the other lines of code, as it only should be used at the end.

Source:
https://www.lua.org/pil/4.4.html

Comment: The function is creating a leaderstats group for each player that joins. It is okay that it ends there.

Comment: if it was used at the end, my code would be inside the playeradded function which would then make it so that my code would only work the first time a player joins.